# Error exporting animation to gif - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif

I am aiming to export an animation as a gif format. I can achieve this using an mp4 but am getting an error when converting to gif. I'm not sure if its the script that wrong or some backend settings.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],        
    'GroupA_X' : [3, 4, 5, 12, 15, 16, 21, 36, 47], 
    'GroupA_Y' : [2, 4, 5, 12, 15, 15, 22, 36, 45],            
    'GroupB_X' : [2, 5, 3, 12, 14, 12, 22, 33, 41],   
    'GroupB_Y' : [2, 4, 3, 13, 13, 14, 24, 32, 45],                 
        })

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_xlim(0,50)
ax.set_ylim(0,50)

def groups():

    Group_A = df1[['Time','GroupA_X','GroupA_Y']]

    GA_X = np.array(Group_A.groupby(['Time'])['GroupA_X'].apply(list))
    GA_Y = np.array(Group_A.groupby(['Time'])['GroupA_Y'].apply(list))

    GA = ax.scatter(GA_X[0], GA_Y[0], c = ['blue'], marker = 'o', s = 10, edgecolor = 'black')

    return GA, GA_X, GA_Y

def animate(i) :

    GA, GA_X, GA_Y = groups()

    GA.set_offsets(np.c_[GA_X[0+i], GA_Y[0+i]])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,3), interval = 1000, blit = False)

# If exporting as an mp4 it works fine.

#Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
#writer = Writer(fps = 10, bitrate = 8000)
#ani.save('ani_test.mp4', writer = writer)


#But if I try to export as a gif it returns an error:

ani.save('gif_test.gif', writer = 'imagemagick')
```

Error:

```
MovieWriter imagemagick unavailable. Trying to use pillow instead.

self._frames[0].save(
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Note: I have also tried the following which returns the same `Index error`

```
my_writer=animation.PillowWriter(fps = 10)
ani.save(filename='gif_test.gif', writer=my_writer)
```

I have tried adjusting numerous settings from other questions [animate gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140952/matplotlib-save-animation-in-gif-error). My current animation settings are as follows. I am using a Mac.

```
###ANIMATION settings
#animation.html :  none            ## How to display the animation as HTML in
                                   ## the IPython notebook. 'html5' uses
                                   ## HTML5 video tag; 'jshtml' creates a 
                                   ## Javascript animation
#animation.writer : imagemagick         ## MovieWriter 'backend' to use
#animation.codec : mpeg4            ## Codec to use for writing movie
#animation.bitrate: -1             ## Controls size/quality tradeoff for movie.
                                   ## -1 implies let utility auto-determine
#animation.frame_format:  png      ## Controls frame format used by temp files
#animation.html_args:              ## Additional arguments to pass to html writer
animation.ffmpeg_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\ffmpeg.exe    ## Path to ffmpeg binary. Without full path
                                   ## $PATH is searched
#animation.ffmpeg_args:            ## Additional arguments to pass to ffmpeg
#animation.avconv_path:  avconv    ## Path to avconv binary. Without full path
                                   ## $PATH is searched
#animation.avconv_args:            ## Additional arguments to pass to avconv
animation.convert_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16-HDRI    ## Path to ImageMagick's convert binary.
                                   ## On Windows use the full path since convert
                                   ## is also the name of a system tool.
#animation.convert_args:           ## Additional arguments to pass to convert
#animation.embed_limit : 20.0
```

Comment: No errors for me. Works well. Issue from IDE?

Comment: Cheers. I thought this might be the case. I'll do some more searching

Comment: You say you're using a Mac but those are Windows paths set for `animation.ffmpeg_path` and `animation.convert_path`. Why is that?

Comment: I followed another question and thought they were for Mac. I'll double check

Comment: @WilliamMiller, could you please point me in the right direction to find relevant settings for a Mac

Comment: Hopefully my answer will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths you have configured,

```
animation.ffmpeg_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\ffmpeg.exe
```

and

```
animation.convert_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16-HDRI
```

Are for Windows, but since you are on Mac you need paths for MacOS. You should be able to get them using [`which`](https://ss64.com/osx/which.html) from the terminal. On my Ubuntu install `which` gives the following

```sh
>$ which convert
/usr/bin/convert

>$ which ffmpeg  
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

It should be similar for MacOS. Those are the paths which need to be supplied to the rcParams `animation.convert_path` and `animation.ffmpeg_path`, i.e.

```
animation.ffmpeg_path: /usr/bin/ffmpeg
animation.convert_path: /usr/bin/convert
```

Do note that while having the wrong paths in the matplotlib configuration would produce the error in question, fixing it may not resolve the error - there might be something else wrong as well.

Comment: So inserting `>$ which convert` into my command terminal will display the correct path?

Comment: @jonboy The `>$` is not part of the command, that's just the way I have my prompt configured. The commands are `which convert` and `which ffmpeg`.

Comment: Thanks. I can find the path for `ffmpeg` but `convert` isn't returning anything.

Comment: @jonboy That indicates an issue either with the `PATH` variable or with the imagemagick installation, you might be able to remedy that by uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick

Comment: Thanks @William Miller. Having all sorts of problems with downloading `imagemagick`. Getting errors while trying to reinstall `brew`. Error:  `Need sudo access on macOS!
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 47 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 49 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 47
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

Comment: Feel like it would be easier to just convert an `mp4` to `gif`!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from a post to of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251965/ffmpeg-file-writer-in-python-2-7). It seems the PillowWriter class is what worked on my computer, I couldn't get over the error arising from the ImageMagick class. You may have a better idea on what to set the bitrate and codec to, these were guesses or copied from the question I mentioned before.

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, new_animate, frames=np.arange(0, 3)
plt.show()

my_writer=animation.PillowWriter(fps=20, codec='libx264', bitrate=2)

ani.save(filename='gif_test.gif', writer=my_writer)
```